# Pub/ Sub - Subscribing to a non-0MQ publisher

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm currently trying to make a proxy with 0MQ. I would like to subscribe to a publisher that is not running under 0MQ. I mean I have the address and the port of a distant publisher that is sending XML files and I want to get that files. Unfortunately, I do not get any messages from the publisher whereas it is well sending.

What I'm doing is (in Python):

```
context    = zmq.Context(1)
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.connect(address)
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '') # I want to subscribe any topics
```

In the same time, I have a publisher sending the received message (if it happens):

```
publisher = context.socket (zmq.PUB)
publisher.bind(publishing_address)
```

Finally,

```
while True:
    data = subscriber.recv()
    print data
    publisher.send(data)
```

I tested my proxy and that works when I'm connect it to a 0MQ publisher but when I'm connected to the non-OMQ publisher that does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid this cannot be achieved because [ØMQ is not a neutral carrier](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#-MQ-is-Not-a-Neutral-Carrier):

> A common question that newcomers to ØMQ ask (it's one I've asked myself) is, "how do I write an XYZ server in ØMQ?" For example, "how do I write an HTTP server in ØMQ?" The implication is that if we use normal sockets to carry HTTP requests and responses, we should be able to use ØMQ sockets to do the same, only much faster and better.
>
> The answer used to be "this is not how it works". **ØMQ is not a neutral carrier, it imposes a framing on the transport protocols it uses. This framing is not compatible with existing protocols, which tend to use their own framing.** For example, compare an HTTP request and a ØMQ request, both over TCP/IP.

Differently put: **ØMQ can only talk with ØMQ**.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the OP could write a "custom subscriber + ZMQ publisher" node that brings the external publisher into a ZMQ network.